# Examples of two/multiple facet scoring?

Tags: layout, info-visualisation, charts, numbers

Working on an interesting scenario - we need to communicate a "score" that has two facets:

1. A percentage based score that has a threshold that must be met to pass (90%)
2. Specific items that must be passed, regardless of the score

- #2 supersedes #1, so even if the user has a passing score in #1, if there are any failures of items in #2, this counts as an overall failure/non-passing.

Visual representation of concepts. Note, each representation shows multiple states, as only one state would be visible at a time.

Does anyone have examples of communicating multi-faceted scoring?

[[image: UI for multi-faceted scoring. Bar chart and half circle chart.1]

Comment: is this score something that users engage with ongoing? In other words, is there communication with a user that actions they take are moving them forward? Similar to surveys or multistep tasks where the progress is shown as they take actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are existing use cases that have a similar criteria, such as a driving test in which certain tasks must be completed successfully to pass the test, and you also can't fail too many tasks.

I think the relationship or the logic is such that you can describe/present the two different criteria in a similar way.

[image]

The reason for presenting both scores in a similar way is to allow the user to understand the relationship between what they scored and what is required to pass. In both cases you have to reach a certain threshold, one of which is a fraction of the total questions and another is a fraction of the specific questions. If you present them differently then the user has to interpret the scores differently and then process the combined result.

The example solution presented allows them to simply scan and see if they are above or below the criteria immediately, and then add the results together to see if they have passed or not. There are other solutions too but this is an illustration of the considerations that would make it easier to interpret and understand.